# Python ignore missing values

Tags: python

I would like to ignore missing values into my python script.
My goal is simply to skip empty entry data and jump to the next line.
Everything is coming from an xml file which look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RegisterSearch TotalResults="6">
  <SearchResults>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088501913376">
      <Filename>55_208_049_EXE_CCR_CIM_SGA_010_A1.zip</Filename>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088501881434">
      <Filename>54_017_306_EXE_CCE_FMP_CIR_025.zip</Filename>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088539553420">
      <Filename>051_030_021_EXE_ACH_LST_MAN_002_A1.7z</Filename>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088580696607">
      <Filename></Filename>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088539570694">
      <Filename>051_030_021_EXE_ACH_LST_MAN_002_A1.7z</Filename>
    </Document>
    <Document DocumentId="1348828088580654972">
      <Filename>51_039_147_EXE_CCE_SID_FIB_001_A1.rar</Filename>
    </Document>
  </SearchResults>
</RegisterSearch>
```

And here is my tiny script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data_out = open('2_download_data.txt', 'w')
tree = ET.parse('1_download_xml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter(tag='Document'):
    for filename in elem:
        if (filename.tag=='Filename'):
            data_out.write('curl -u john:doe -o ' +'"'+ (filename.text) +'" '+ 'https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/' +""+ str(elem.get('DocumentId'))+"\n")
data_out.close()
```

At the end, I export the result into a text file, which is working fine.
I am looking for something as below :

```
curl -u john:doe -o "55_208_049_EXE_CCR_CIM_SGA_010_A1.zip" https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/1348828088501913376
curl -u john:doe -o "54_017_306_EXE_CCE_FMP_CIR_025.zip" https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/1348828088501881434
curl -u john:doe -o "051_030_021_EXE_ACH_LST_MAN_002_A1.7z" https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/1348828088539553420
curl -u john:doe -o "051_030_021_EXE_ACH_LST_MAN_002_A1.7z" https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/1348828088539570694
curl -u john:doe -o "51_039_147_EXE_CCE_SID_FIB_001_A1.rar" https://my.web.link.uk/projects/268441485/1348828088580654972
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: `if filename.tag=='Filename' and filename.text:`

Comment: You would probably be fine, if you just add: `if filename.text is None: continue` to your code.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp, you have make my day ! Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Another improvement but off topic: You could use `xpath` for searching appropriate elements: `filenames = root.findall('./SearchResults/Document/Filename')`